# Netlify + Azure Static Web Apps displaying website poorly compared to AWS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, azure, netlify

I've deployed my webapp to three places.

A) Azure https://lively-tree-0a47f530f-25.eastus2.azurestaticapps.net/

B) Netlify https://61f64cc36e1f8a0008d040f7--heuristic-engelbart-3deb1a.netlify.app/

C) AWS EB http://automatedclassification-env.eba-58mhr3yb.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/

This is all exactly the same code being deployed, but if you upload images and navigate to `/select`, you'll see that the UI for (A) and (B) are so out of place compared to (C).

I should also mention that how it looks on AWS is how it looks on localhost.

I'm really really confused. Why would 1/3 hosting platforms seemingly randomly work?

The app is written using Node 14.18.1, react scripts, React, and react router. The second page that looks all wrong on (A) and (B) is a very trivial implementation of https://github.com/UniversalDataTool/react-image-annotate

Something else I noticed is that I can get the behavior to correct by manually going back, and going forward: https://streamable.com/qo6nob

I am going to raise an issue with the creator of the library being used.

Comment: Not much to go on, based on just links to your site. FYI this isn't the place to have people reach out to you for repo access (I removed this from your question, accordingly). All needed info needs to be in the question itself. Lastly: as written, this is off-topic here, and would fit better on ServerFault (as there is no programming question here, and it's focused on infrastructure).

Comment: it may not be much to go off of but I would be surprised if people haven't run into discrepancies with app deployment between providers before and what I'm trying to determine is if that's my code's fault or the provider